# Android Setup constraint for view2 to follow start of view1. But view1 has constraint to start of its parent

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I cannot achieve this one.
I want viewB to follow the start of viewA.
Then I want to create a constraint to have a space from the start of viewA to its parent.

[image]
.

Code I tried:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionTxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Txt1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionTxt2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Txt2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/descriptionTxt"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/descriptionTxt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descriptionTxt" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The code above will show in Preview that only viewA will have a margin from the left. viewB does not follow the left of viewA.

Im using com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `match_parent`. Instead, start using "0dp" for `match_parent` and define left/right or top/bottom parent constraints

Here is working code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_margin="10dp"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/descriptionTxt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Txt1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/descriptionTxt2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Txt2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/descriptionTxt"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/descriptionTxt"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descriptionTxt" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also , it is good to use Guidelines to have uniform left/top/right/bottom margin.

Answer (score 2):

> try this :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descriptionTxt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Txt1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descriptionTxt2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Txt2"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/descriptionTxt"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/descriptionTxt"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descriptionTxt"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```